# Creating a URL mapping for my ReactJS app running in development mode

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webserver, url-routing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a ReactJS app running on development mode, on port number `3000`. I am trying to create a mapping with Nginx so that all requests at `avt1.example.com/demo` gets routed to `http://localhost:3000/demo` but this just does not work and all I see is a blank page.

But if I try `avt1.example.com:3000/demo`, it works as expected. I cannot understand where am I going wrong. Here is the configuration file I created for Nginx and `example.com`

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name avt1.example.com www.avt1.example.com;
        location /demo {
                # pass to ReactJS app
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location / {
                # pass to NodeJS app
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

What is it that I am missing or doing incorrectly? I started the react-app using `yarn start` and works just fine if I provide the port number with the domain.

Also, if there is a suggestion of running the ReactJS app in a better way, please let me know.

Comment: iam kinda confused by your question :/ how do you run your webserver and how do your run your backend ? On one line you mention ngnix, but is nginx running on docker or just a virtual maschine? Btw. you said that when you enter the url avt1.example.com:3000/demo everything is working as expected, then everything is fine right? (even avt1.example.com:3000/ should working already..?) that is how ngnix works. or do you mean you want to have avt1.example.com/demo ??? One thing to mention you try also instead of using localhost, use 0.0.0.0

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass This is running in a azure VM. Yes, I want to run this as `avt1.example.com/demo`. Do not want to include the port number.

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass Would you know this?

Comment: i will post an answer today, give me some, i need to look into my source(it's been a while since i have touched it xD ) btw could you add your node js code as well? I wanna make sure that you haven't any url mappings as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing the node js code, so i guess you set up the "demo" url as well in the nodejs code there. So you need to edit you site-enable config to the following

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name avt1.example.com www.avt1.example.com;
        location /demo {
                # pass to ReactJS app
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/demo;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location / {
                # pass to NodeJS app
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

but the better readable would be

```
# pass to ReactJS app
upstream demotool {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000/demo;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name avt1.example.com www.avt1.example.com;
        location /demo {
                proxy_pass demotool;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

i don't the a reason to proxy pass the backend stuff right now